# Which Index Works Better with pg_trgm Extension?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-14

I'm currently building indexing for pattern matching in PostgreSQL database. After reading some articles, I decided to use `pg_trgm` extension. But according to this [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/pgtrgm.html#id-1.11.7.42.8) we can use both GIN or GIST index.

I'm just curious which index works better with `pg_trgm`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the query you want to optimize.

If the query looks like

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE col % 'string'
```

a GIN index usually works better.

If the query looks like

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY col <-> 'string'
LIMIT 1
```

you need to use a GiST index, because a GIN index cannot support that.

Comment: I'm going to use `LIKE` operator, so it's GIN, isn't it?

Comment: Typically yes. Why don't you run a test with a bigger data set?

Comment: currently I'm building big mock data. but get this error when inserting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10399727/psqlexception-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-tra